# Ubuntu Live Setup without interior laptop lcd

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, display

I'd like to run ubuntu on my ex-laptop. It had win7 or 10. I formatted all data on HDD so it has no OS now. Big problem is that the laptops interior LCD has broken years ago and I will use it with a second monitor. However, the bios screen or booting screens couldn't be displayed on the second screen so I don't know any idea what happens there. I got problems with ubuntu 20.4 with another computer like i386 not supported. Maybe problem is that but I'm not sure. How can I install an OS without an interior screen?

Comment: "However, the bios screen or booting screens couldn't be displayed on the second screen" That is a hardware error and happens well before the OS comes into play. Maybe have  the display fixed? Or get a replacement?

Comment: I've successfully used *live* systems on laptops with dead screens, using the fn-monitor keys until it mirrors the laptop display & external so it shows the same image, or using external monitor only (toggling between mirror, intnernal only, external only, side-by-side..). This doesn't work as well on some boxes as others (ie. firmware), and may only work for some Ubuntu ISOs (I can't recall if it worked with the *di* installer, I always used it with `ubiquity` *live* installer ISOs). Your mention of i386 though confuses me; Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is still supported for i386/i686 only hardware.

Comment: @Rinzwind external monitor doesnt get data b4 os comes into play, before I deleted windows it was working so I don't think its a hardware problem. replacement lcd is expensive on my country. Also i got working system, so i cant pay for new things.

Comment: @guiverc Fn commands doesn't work without os, i tried a lot fn+f4 (which was the key for second monitor) also windows+P but couldn't mirror. I tried it with 20.4 and rufus. I'll try with your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I mentioned using the Fn+Monitor key using *live* systems (no OS installed; the OS running *live* from thumb-drive, dvd/cd etc).  I've used it on thinkpads, dell laptops... successfully.  (not super+P but the keys marked blue-grey provided eg. fn+f7 on nearby thinkpad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably problem was that USB couldn't boot himself. So I removed the HDD, wrote Ubuntu 20.04 iso on it. I placed HDD which has the installer on HDD slot on the motherboard so I wouldn't have to change booting priority. Plugged another HDD via USB slot. The live installer showed up. I installed ubuntu to HDD which in the USB slot. After installation removed HDD placed on the motherboard and placed the HDD which I installed ubuntu, in the motherboard slot. Then worked well. Thank u a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try closing the lid of the laptop after you turn it on? Usually that forces output to secondary display if it's connected.

(Hopefully it doesn't shutdown automatically with lid closed.)

Comment: I completely removed the lid before. I tried both hinges open or close. It didn't force sadly.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Maybe look if you'll notice a switch that hinges (should) press when closed and press it manually?

Sorry, that was my best idea.

Edit actually one more.. do you have keys marked in blue, usually, that respond to Function key "Fn"? Some laptops have key combo that switches displays on keypress. And rotates like screen1/screen2/both screens(mirror) etc